# kotlin reading from file into byte array

Tags: android, kotlin

How do I read bytes into a Byte Array?  In java I used to initialize byte array as `byte[] b = new byte[100]` and then pass that to the corresponding method. However in Kotlin, I am unable to initialize `ByteArray` with how many bytes the buffer should have.

In other words, how do I use this function?:
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/io/RandomAccessFile#read(kotlin.ByteArray)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The easiest way is to use

```
File("aaa").readBytes()
```

That one will read the whole file into the `ByteArray`. But you should carefully know you have enough RAM in the heap to do so

The ByteArray can be created via `ByteArray(100)` call, where `100` is the size of it

For the `RandomAccessFile`, it is probably better to use at the `readFully` function, which reads exactly the requested amount of bytes.

The classic approach is possible to read a file by chunks, e.g.

```
    val buff = ByteArray(1230)
    File("aaa").inputStream().buffered().use { input ->
      while(true) {
        val sz = input.read(buff)
        if (sz <= 0) break

        ///at that point we have a sz bytes in the buff to process
        consumeArray(buff, 0, sz)
      }
    }
```

Comment: I mean I may not have enough bytes to fit, so I want to declare an array of fixed size, then read into it part by part..

Comment: I already tried it.. If I initialize as `val buf: ByteArray(100)`, it shows error at `(` saying unexpected tokens...

Comment: I've update the post to cover your case, also, see how I use the ByteArray in the example above (replace : with =)

Answer (score 8):

I found this worked nicely:

```
fun File.chunkedSequence(chunk: Int): Sequence<ByteArray> {
    val input = this.inputStream().buffered()
    val buffer = ByteArray(chunk)
    return generateSequence {
        val red = input.read(buffer)
        if (red >= 0) buffer.copyOf(red)
        else {
            input.close()
            null
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this.

```
    file.chunkedSequence(CHUNK_SIZE).forEach {
        // Do something with `it`
    }
```

Not an exact match to your question but this is the question that came up when I was looking to chunk a file into a sequence of byte arrays.

Comment: Worked beautifully!

Comment: Nice! But why isnt something like this part of the common libs?

Answer (score 2):

```
File.readBytes() //limited 2GB
```

Don't forget it has an internal limitation of 2 GB byte array size. So to read all bytes we should use stream like:

```
FileInputStream(File(uri)).use {
    val allBytes = it.readBytes()
}
```

Also you can use readAllBytes for Android API >= 26:

```
Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath))
```